# Error 404 for all website pages when setting up asp net

Tags: asp.net, apache, mod-mono

I'm trying to set up a asp net website using mod_mono on ubuntu using apache. Currently I'm getting an error where everything returns an error 404 from the apache server.

[image: Error]

Here's the conf for the website (I've replaced some stuff to keep some privacy, such as the ip and site name)

```
<VirtualHost ---------->
DocumentRoot /home/euan/ftp/files/Site
ServerName Site.org
HostNameLookups on
ServerAlias www.Site.org
<Directory "/home/euan/ftp/files/Site">
allow from all
Options None
SetHandler mono
Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Can anyone help me with this? Is this something silly like an incompatibility between the mono and asp.net frameworks? Or are my configs wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sum up what happened here, it was an incompatibility between the Microsoft asp.net and the mono version, when switching to the mono version and reworking everything this error went away.